# Accessing Bugzilla from .NET

Tags: .net, bugzilla

I have a .NET application and I would like to create a bug in bugzilla database from my application.

I have found a [C# proxy for this purpose which is using WebService interface of Bugzilla.](http://oss.dbc.dk/bugzproxy/)

Unfortunately, it does not work for me and I get connection timeout error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Casal

Comment: Why not ask the bugzproxy mailing list or submit a bug to it before giving up on it?

Comment: They have frozen the development John.

Comment: What version of Bugzilla are you testing against? It looks like the latest version of bugzproxy is for 3.0 series which is a few years old.  I'm fairly certain there have been changes to the web service since 3.0.

Comment: I just tried this with the current version of the C# proxy and XMLRPC against a Bugzilla 3.4.5 install it worked fine. Maybe you have some other issue, e.g. incorrect URL or firewall.